# Trying to click this button in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have the following code:

```
casper.start("my link here", function() {
    this.click('.btn btn-primary circle right');
});

casper.run();
```

I am getting the error `CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: .btn btn-primary circle right`

If I inspect the element in chrome it looks like `<button class="btn btn-primary circle right" data-reactid=".3.1.0.0.0.1.3.0.0.0.$right" data-label="right" data-action="Pagination" data-search-track="true"></button>`

I can also do `console.log(this.getPageContent());` and I can see the button in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your click in waitFor callback

```
var url = 'your url';
var selector = '.btn btn-primary circle right';

casper.start(url)
.waitForSelector(selector, function() {
  this.click(selector);
})
.run();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but no cigar. I really think this is some issue at a very high level. I can't get any click event to work. Even copy/paste from the docs for the click example gives me the same error. Right now I have capserjs v 1.1.4. I am going to try an older version and see if I get a different result.

Comment: Before you do, can you listen to `page.error` and `remote.message` events and start casper in verbose mode with log level of debug and post your log?

Comment: Mario how do I do that? https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/b6b2bd7743e28460c03d2d6f0d134ed5?

Comment: For catching errors pls check this gist https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf and for verbose mode simply call `casperjs --verbose --log-level=debug script.js`